# Arrayformula, Omit Certain Columns and Merge

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am working on a table in which I need to extract the contents of certain columns based on the row "Type".  For example if Row 3 has a Version "Type 1", then I need to extract Columns 1, 3 and 5 from that row.  I need to place an "x" for Columns 2 and 4.

I have already created an array formula that will let me know which columns I need to extract, what I can't figure out is how to merge the data into one column in the order that I need.

```
Cols   |     Type   |   1   |   2   |   3  |   4   |   5   |
1,3,5  |   TYPE 1   |   A   |   B   |   C  |   D   |   E   |
```

For the sample above, I should get:  A_X_C_X_E

I have included a sample table via the link below to better explain.

As far as the table, this is coming from a query, so I cannot just clear the columns for each row that are useless.

I eventually will end up using the data in another table that has the same number of columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0Z_czPBqp7Jb9XDdPLigDQAZ8WkDLyo0qGcHk5re6o/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(""&G1:K1, SUBSTITUTE(E3:E, "_", "|")), G3:K, "x"))
 ,,99^99)), " ", "_"), "^_.*_$", ))
```

[image: 0]